# How to hide a menu item when logged in, in Orchard 1.6

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm using the content permission module on a custom link menu item to try and hide it when a user is logged in.

In the menu I have two custom link items, a "My Pages" item and a "Login" item, the "My Pages" I successfully hide from non authenticated users by removing the view permission for "Anonymous" users. However when I try to do the reverse and remove view rights for everybody but "Anonymous" users to hide it after someone logs in, it does not seem to work.

I've looked in the security code, like for example the code pointed out in the following http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/395052 post, but I just can't make much sense of it.

Any thoughts or advice on this would be most appreciated.

Cheers. 
Ola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using a Content Item link for the "My Pages" link.  These will be properly permission checked.  I'm just guessing that the link to Logon is a custom link where you put the url in directly.  These links are not permissions checked as far as I know.

A couple of options I can think of are 1. Move the login link to a separate menu and just have a logged in menu, and a logged out menu with the proper links on each.  Then, just use widget layers to hide/show the correct menu.  2.  Make your own menu item type that you can write custom code for to hide/show based on whatever you want.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the items are indeed custom links. I had the same idea about creating separate menus and putting them on different layers, so I think I'll just do that.

Comment: Ok cool. As long as your menus don't get too complex that sounds like a pretty good approach. Good luck!